# Reading my own Jar's Manifest

Tags: java, osgi, manifest.mf, apache-felix

I need to read the `Manifest` file, which delivered my class, but when I use:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResources(...)
```

I get the `MANIFEST` from the first `.jar` loaded into the Java Runtime.
My app will be running from an applet or a webstart,
so I will not have access to my own `.jar` file, I guess.

I actually want to read the `Export-package` attribute from the `.jar` which started
the Felix OSGi, so I can expose those packages to Felix. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the FrameworkUtil.getBundle() answer below is the best. It answers what you *actually* want to do (get the bundle's exports) rather than what you asked (read the manifest).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. Call `getResources()` and iterate through the returned collection of URLs, reading them as manifests until you find yours:

   ```
    Enumeration<URL> resources = getClass().getClassLoader()
      .getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        try {
          Manifest manifest = new Manifest(resources.nextElement().openStream());
          // If the line above leads to <null> manifest Attributes try from JarInputStream:
          // Manifest manifest = resources.nextElement().openStream().getManifest();

          // check that this is your manifest and do what you need or get the next one
          ...
        } catch (IOException E) {
          // handle
        }
    }
   ```
2. You can try checking whether `getClass().getClassLoader()` is an instance of `java.net.URLClassLoader`. Majority of Sun classloaders are, including `AppletClassLoader`.
   You can then cast it and call `findResource()` which has been known - for applets, at least - to return the needed manifest directly:

   ```
    URLClassLoader cl = (URLClassLoader) getClass().getClassLoader();
    try {
      URL url = cl.findResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
      Manifest manifest = new Manifest(url.openStream());
      // do stuff with it
      ...
    } catch (IOException E) {
      // handle
    }
   ```

Comment: Perfect! I never knew you could iterate through resources with the same name.

Comment: How do you know the classloader is only aware of a single .jar file? (true in many cases I suppose) I would much rather use something associated directly with the class in question.

Comment: it's a **good practice** to make **separate** answers for each one, instead of including the 2 fixes in one answer. Separate answers can be voted independently.

Comment: just a note: I needed something similar but I'm inside a WAR on JBoss, so the second approach didn't work for me. I ended up with a variant of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1283496/160799

Comment: @chris-dolan Gave the correct answer to this question (see comment above).

Comment: +1; BTW, I've just found that EAR/META-INF/... is not included into the runtime classpath (on Weblogic 10.3.5), so it cannot be inspected as a resource.

Comment: Thanks to add the wiring around `java.util.jar.Manifest`.  I didn't know about that class before I read that post.  I probably would have dumbly / manually parsed the Manifest file myself...

Comment: Manifest is giving me a rather useless empty map, so I still have to parse it manually. Still useful code to get the resource at first, though.

Comment: The first option didn't work for me. I got the manifests of my 62 dependency jars, but not the one where the current class was defined...

Comment: Option 2 appears to have stopped working as-of java 11 (maybe java 9).

Comment: For future also-stumblers: If `new Manifest(resources.nextElement().openStream())` leads to `<null>` manifest `Attributes` try `resources.nextElement().openStream().getManifest()` from [`JarInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html#method-summary).

Answer (score 126):

You can find the URL for your class first. If it's a JAR, then you load the manifest from there. For example,

```
Class clazz = MyClass.class;
String className = clazz.getSimpleName() + ".class";
String classPath = clazz.getResource(className).toString();
if (!classPath.startsWith("jar")) {
  // Class not from JAR
  return;
}
String manifestPath = classPath.substring(0, classPath.lastIndexOf("!") + 1) + 
    "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
Manifest manifest = new Manifest(new URL(manifestPath).openStream());
// If the line above leads to <null> manifest Attributes try instead from JarInputStream:
//Manifest manifest = new URL(manifestPath).openStream().getManifest();
Attributes attr = manifest.getMainAttributes();
String value = attr.getValue("Manifest-Version");
```

Comment: I like this solution as it gets your own manifest directly rather than having to search for it.

Comment: can be improved a little bit by removing condition check `classPath.replace("org/example/MyClass.class", "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"`

Comment: Who closes the stream?

Comment: This does not work in inner classes, because `getSimpleName` removes the outer class name. This will work for inner classes: `clazz.getName().replace (".", "/") + ".class"`.

Comment: You need to close the stream, the manifest constructor does not.

Comment: Note that functions attr.containsKey("Manifest-Version") and attr.get("Manifest-Version") will return null since those functions require arguments that are of the inner class Attribute.Name.  Unfortunately the functions accept Object... so there's no compile-time error when giving it a String, but it will return a null value.  So stick with Attribute.getValue() as show in the example above. Attributes.getValue() explicitly accepts a String, and then wraps it in a new Attributes.Name for you.  (I know this is because Attributes implements Map, but it's just not safe API coding in my opinion.)

Comment: For future also-stumblers: If `new Manifest(new URL(manifestPath).openStream())` leads to `<null>` manifest `Attributes` try `new URL(manifestPath).openStream().getManifest()` from [`JarInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html#method-summary).

Answer (score 22):

You can use [`Manifests`](http://manifests.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.7.5/com/jcabi/manifests/Manifests.html) from [jcabi-manifests](http://manifests.jcabi.com/) and read any attribute from any of available MANIFEST.MF files with just one line:

```
String value = Manifests.read("My-Attribute");
```

The only dependency you need is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcabi-manifests</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, see this blog post for more details: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/07/03/how-to-read-manifest-mf.html

Comment: Very nice libraries. Is there a way to control the log level?

Comment: All jcabi libs log through SLF4J. You can dispatch log messages using any facility you wish, for example log4j or logback

Comment: if using logback.xml the line you need to add is like `<logger name="com.jcabi.manifests" level="OFF"/>`

Comment: Multiple manifests from the same classloader overlap and overwrite each other

Answer (score 22):

I will admit up front that this answer does not answer the original question, that of generally being able to access the Manifest. However if what is really required is to read one of a number of "standard" Manifest attributes, the following solution is much simpler than those posted above. Note that this solution is in Kotlin, not Java, but I would expect that a port to Java would be trivial. (Although I admit I don't know the Java equivalent of ".`package`".

In my case I wanted to read the attribute "Implementation-Version" so I started with the solutions given above to obtain the stream and then read it to obtain the value. While this solution worked, a coworker reviewing my code showed me an easier way to do what I wanted. Note that this solution is in Kotlin, not Java.

```
val myPackage = MyApplication::class.java.`package`
val implementationVersion = myPackage.implementationVersion
```

Once again note that this does not answer the original question, in particular "Export-package" does not seem to be one of the supported attributes. That said, there is a myPackage.name that returns a value. Perhaps someone who understands this more than I can comment on whether that returns the value the original poster is requesting.

Comment: Indeed, the java port is straightforward: `String implementationVersion = MyApplication.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();`

Comment: It fact this is what I was looking for. I'm also happy that Java has also an equivalent.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way is to use JarURLConnection class :

```
String className = getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class";
String classPath = getClass().getResource(className).toString();
if (!classPath.startsWith("jar")) {
    return DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE;
}

URL url = new URL(classPath);
JarURLConnection jarConnection = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
Manifest manifest = jarConnection.getManifest();
Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
return attributes.getValue(PROPERTY_NAME);
```

Because in some cases `...class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();` gives path with `vfs:/`, so this should be handled additionally.

Comment: This is, by far, the easiest and cleanest way to do it.

Comment: @walen And, furthermore, it should be promoted more up the answer stack since code in the top two answers that returned `<null>` where it shouldn't took me quite a while. I left according comments there (and downvoted) but who reads (hidden, at first) comments...

Comment: @GeroldBroser I upvoted your comments, but if you really care about visibility you can always edit both answers to add a `//comment` above the `new Manifest()` part showing the alternative.

Answer (score 12):

The following code works with multiple types of archives (jar, war) and multiple types of classloaders (jar, url, vfs, ...)

```
  public static Manifest getManifest(Class<?> clz) {
    String resource = "/" + clz.getName().replace(".", "/") + ".class";
    String fullPath = clz.getResource(resource).toString();
    String archivePath = fullPath.substring(0, fullPath.length() - resource.length());
    if (archivePath.endsWith("\\WEB-INF\\classes") || archivePath.endsWith("/WEB-INF/classes")) {
      archivePath = archivePath.substring(0, archivePath.length() - "/WEB-INF/classes".length()); // Required for wars
    }

    try (InputStream input = new URL(archivePath + "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF").openStream()) {
      return new Manifest(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Loading MANIFEST for class " + clz + " failed!", e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can result of `clz.getResource(resource).toString()` have backslashes?

Answer (score 11):

I believe the most appropriate way to get the manifest for any bundle (including the bundle which loaded a given class) is to use the Bundle or BundleContext object.

```
// If you have a BundleContext
Dictionary headers = bundleContext.getBundle().getHeaders();

// If you don't have a context, and are running in 4.2
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());
bundle.getHeaders();
```

Note that the Bundle object also provides `getEntry(String path)` to look up resources contained within a specific bundle, rather than searching that bundle's entire classpath.

In general, if you want bundle-specific information, do not rely upon assumptions about the classloaders, just use the OSGi APIs directly.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler way to do this is to use getPackage().
For example, to get Implementation-Version:

```
Application.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question specifically, but it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can use getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() like this :

```
URL url = Menu.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
File file = DataUtilities.urlToFile(url);
JarFile jar = null;
try {
    jar = new JarFile(file);
    Manifest manifest = jar.getManifest();
    Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
    return attributes.getValue("Built-By");
} finally {
    jar.close();
}
```

Comment: `getCodeSource` may return `null`. What are the criteria, that this will work? The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource%28%29) does not explain this.

Comment: Where is `DataUtilities` imported from? It doesn't seem to be in the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you including the getClassLoader step? If you say "this.getClass().getResource()" you should be getting resources relative to the calling class. I've never used ClassLoader.getResource(), though from a quick look at the Java Docs it sounds like that will get you the first resource of that name found in any current classpath.

Comment: If your class is named "com.mypackage.MyClass", calling `class.getResource("myresource.txt")` will try to load that resource from `com/mypackage/myresource.txt`. How exactly are you going to use this approach to get the manifest?

Comment: Okay, I have to backtrack. That's what comes of not testing. I was thinking that you could say this.getClass().getResource("../../META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") (However many ".."'s are necessary given your package name.) But while that works for class files in a directory to work your way up a directory tree, it apparently doesn't work for JARs. I don't see why not, but that's how it is. Nor does this.getClass().getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") work -- that gets me the manifest for rt.jar. (To be continued ...)

Comment: What you can do is use getResource to find the path to your own class file, then strip off everything after the "!" to get the path to the jar, then append "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF". Like Zhihong suggested, so I'm voting his up.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static Manifest getManifest( Class<?> cl ) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
      URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)cl.getClassLoader();
      String classFilePath = cl.getName().replace('.','/')+".class";
      URL classUrl = classLoader.getResource(classFilePath);
      if ( classUrl==null ) return null;
      String classUri = classUrl.toString();
      if ( !classUri.startsWith("jar:") ) return null;
      int separatorIndex = classUri.lastIndexOf('!');
      if ( separatorIndex<=0 ) return null;
      String manifestUri = classUri.substring(0,separatorIndex+2)+"META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
      URL url = new URL(manifestUri);
      inputStream = url.openStream();
      return new Manifest( inputStream );
    } catch ( Throwable e ) {
      // handle errors
      ...
      return null;
    } finally {
      if ( inputStream!=null ) {
        try {
          inputStream.close();
        } catch ( Throwable e ) {
          // ignore
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This answer uses a very complex and error prone way of loading the Manifest. the much simpler solution is to use `cl.getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")`.

Comment: Did you try it? What jar manifest it will get if you have multiple jars in classpath? It will take the first one that is not what you need. My code solves this problem and it really works.

Comment: I did not criticize the way how you us e the classloader for loading a specific resource. I was pointing out that all the code between `classLoader.getResource(..)` and `url.openStream()` is totally irrelevant and error prone as it tries to do the same as `classLoader.getResourceAsStream(..)` does.

Comment: Nope. It is different. My code takes manifest from the specific jar where the class is located rather than from the the first jar in the classpath.

Comment: Your "jar specific loading code" is equivalent to the following two lines: `ClassLoader classLoader = cl.getClassLoader();
return new Manifest(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));`

Comment: indeed  this  solution  can  be  refactored  but  it  works.  The  two  liners  solution proposed  by  Robert  ends-up  with  NullPointerException in spring boot  applications.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me :

```
Package pck=this.getClass().getPackage();
String msgVersion =  pck.getImplementationTitle()
+ " version:" + pck.getImplementationVersion()
+ " by " + pck.getImplementationVendor();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the solution from Anthony Juckel but in the MANIFEST.MF the key have to start with uppercase.

So my MANIFEST.MF file contain a key like:

**Mykey:** value

Then in the activator or another class you can use the code from Anthony to read the MANIFEST.MF file and the the value that you need.

```
// If you have a BundleContext 
Dictionary headers = bundleContext.getBundle().getHeaders();

// If you don't have a context, and are running in 4.2 
Bundle bundle = `FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()); 
bundle.getHeaders();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this weird solution that runs war applications in a embedded Jetty server but these apps need also to run on standard Tomcat servers, and we have some special properties in the manfest.

The problem was that when in Tomcat, the manifest could be read, but when in jetty, a random manifest was picked up (which missed the special properties)

Based on Alex Konshin's answer, I came up with the following solution (the inputstream is then used in a Manifest class):

```
private static InputStream getWarManifestInputStreamFromClassJar(Class<?> cl ) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)cl.getClassLoader();
        String classFilePath = cl.getName().replace('.','/')+".class";
        URL classUrl = classLoader.getResource(classFilePath);
        if ( classUrl==null ) return null;
        String classUri = classUrl.toString();
        if ( !classUri.startsWith("jar:") ) return null;
        int separatorIndex = classUri.lastIndexOf('!');
        if ( separatorIndex<=0 ) return null;
        String jarManifestUri = classUri.substring(0,separatorIndex+2);
        String containingWarManifestUri = jarManifestUri.substring(0,jarManifestUri.indexOf("WEB-INF")).replace("jar:file:/","file:///") + MANIFEST_FILE_PATH;
        URL url = new URL(containingWarManifestUri);
        inputStream = url.openStream();
        return inputStream;
    } catch ( Throwable e ) {
        // handle errors
        LOGGER.warn("No manifest file found in war file",e);
        return null;
    }
}
```