# Provide xsd schema in jar

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jar

I have written a little library. Now I want to let the user configure the lib with a xml file just like in spring. I have a xsd file to validate the xml config and therefore I have a few questions. Is it possible to achive this spring like configuration with a noNamespaceSchemaLocation? Where should I put the xsd in the lib in order to access it form both lib an outside? And how can I get access to the xsd without needing an absolute path? Currently it's more important to get the functionallity inside the lib than from outside.

Thanks, 
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions

1. Is it possible to achive this spring like configuration with a
   noNamespaceSchemaLocation?
2. Where should I put the xsd in the lib in order to access it form both
   lib an outside?
3. And how can I get access to the xsd without needing an absolute path?

Tries to answer ;)

1) Don't know Spring. " NonameSpaceSchemaLocation" support is parser specific i think.

2,3) [How to find resources in the Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/need-to-read-own-jars-manifest-and-not-root-classloaders-manifest)