# Display the version number in Java Cache Viewer

Tags: java, caching, viewer

I'm developing an applet and I've recently added a `MANIFEST` file to
it for version information.

My original intent was to see the version of the applet shown in the
Java Applet Cache Viewer...

```
Java Control Panel -> Temporary Internet Files -> Settings... -> View Applets...
```

But in the cache viewer, it **doesn't show the version number**. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/need-to-read-own-jars-manifest-and-not-root-classloaders-manifest

Answer (score 0):

The Java Applet Cache Viewer was not designed for that.  If you wish to display the information in your own applet at user request, pop a `JOptionPane` with the following information.

```
Package pckg = this.getClass().getPackage();
String title = pckg.getImplementationTitle();
String vendor = pckg.getImplementationVendor();
String version = pckg.getImplementationVersion();
```

Note that the manifest information is available on a per package basis, while a Jar might contain several applets and many packages.