# How to pass variable value defined in build.xml to Java class

Tags: java, ant

Please provide a way to pass variable value defined in build.xml to Java class

Answer (score 3):

Your build process is one thing, your app running is another. You can't pass a build parameter to a class at runtime.

Perhaps a solution to your problem would be to write your parameter found in `build.xml` to `manifest.mf`, and then read it from there at runtime.

You can do it like this:

```
build.xml
<manifest file="MANIFEST.MF">
    <attribute name="MyParameter" value="123"/>
</manifest>
```

And in your java file, take a look at the answer [Reading my own Jar's Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/reading-my-own-jars-manifest).

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, can you please elaborate your solution suggested

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an XML parser to do that. Read this for more info http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152