# Should class.getPackage() return manifest.mf information for an unpacked manifest?

Tags: java

An experiment seems to show that having META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in a directory in classpath is not sufficient to cause Class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion() to return a value, at least, a top-level value.

That is, of my manifest.mf contains:

```
Implementation-Version: 4.3.100
```

(nothing per-package), I'm assuming that Class.getPackage().... will return the string for all classes in the JAR file, and this does not seem to work when the files are 'loose'.

Have I misunderstood the contract or do I need to look or something stupid?

Comment: Long time no answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/reading-my-own-jars-manifest