# Reading my own Jar's manifest, when the Jar is used in an Android app

Tags: java, android, jar, classloader, manifest.mf

I have a Jar that I use in my Android app (it's in the libs folder).
The Jar doesn't contains any Android resources or anything like that, but just simple Java classes.

Now, I want the Jar to know which version it currently has in the manifest so that in case of an exception occurring in the Jar, I know what version of the Jar caused the exception.

For some reason, I can't seem to be able to do it...
I've seen this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/reading-my-own-jars-manifest) and many others, and while this works when I use the Jar in a simple Java app, it doesn't when used in an android app.
I've tried getting the manifest by doing this

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

or this

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

but I never get the manifest for my jar.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While you can perhaps obtain the version of the APK, it's not clear how you would get the version of the jar, since the jar does not survive as a distinct entity in the compiled package.  Can you embed it as some sort of constant field?

Answer (score -1):

***I put this in my subclassed android.app.Application but you can use it anywhere you have a context. Just change getPackageManager() to context.getPackageManager().***

```
public int getVersion() {
    int v = 0;
    try {
        v = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // Huh? Really?
    }
    return v;
}
```

You can use the above method to get the version of your Application from the manifest.