# can a jar file, like a .net assembly, be versioned programmatically?

Tags: java, jar, versioning, .net-assembly

When I right click on a .net exe file and go to "properties" and then "details" there is an entry named "File Version" which corresponds to the value specified in the System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersion assembly attribute as well as an entry named "Product Version" which corresponds to the value specified in the System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion assembly attribute.

Can the same information be included in a jar (zip) file? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

java *.jar files commonly have a manifest file under /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF which might contain various attributes, among which is version information.
for more information look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html).

unfotunately reading the contents of this manifest [isnt as simple as what you described for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/reading-my-own-jars-manifest)