# How to display SVN revision stored in war manifest.mf file on Tapestry5 page?

Tags: java, maven, war, tapestry, manifest.mf

I'm using buildnumber-maven-plugin and maven-war-plugin to generate and put SVN revision into manifest.mf file in my WAR file as an entry.

```
<Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
```

So far, so good.

I would like to display it on Tapestry page (5.3.6 version). How would I do that? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Question previously answered :

[Reading my own Jar's Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/reading-my-own-jars-manifest)

[Manifest API on JDK Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html t:type="layout" title="" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <div>
        <h4>Version:</h4>
             ${project.version}
        <h4>Revision:</h4>
            ${buildNumber}
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your **MANIFEST.MF**

<strike>Implementation-Build</strike>

Implementation-Version: 11111

In your **AppModule.java**

```
public static void contributeApplicationDefaults(MappedConfiguration<String, String> configuration) {
    .......
    String version = "0";
    if (null != AppModule.class.getPackage()) {
        version = AppModule.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    }

    configuration.add(SymbolConstants.APPLICATION_VERSION, version);
    .......
}
```

Add property in your page class

```
@Inject
@Symbol(SymbolConstants.APPLICATION_VERSION)
@Property
protected String buildNumber;
```

Comment: hey, thank you, I will try it out.
I've noticed that my solution displays buildnumber of the particular page only, which is wrong.