# How to read meta data from Manifest file

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I'm trying to extract information from my manifest file to display in one of the methods in my `jar` file, but seem to be having some issues.  Any help is appreciated.

**Manifest file:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.example.package1.myClass

Name: com/example/package1
Specification-Title: MyPackage
Specification-Version: v1.1
Specification-Vendor: MyCompanyName
Implementation-Title: MP
Implementation-Version: 2015-11-05-C
Implementation-Vendor: MyName

Name: com/example/package2
Specification-Title: MySecondaryPackage
Specification-Version: v2.0
Specification-Vendor: MyCompanyName
Implementation-Title: M2ndP
Implementation-Version: 2015-11-05-C
Implementation-Vendor: MyName
```

**myClass.java:**

```
package com.example.package1;
import com.example.package2;

class myClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      myClass clz = new myClass();
      Thread.sleep(10000); //pause 10 seconnds so we can see what's spit out
    } catch (Exception e) {
    //excluded in example
    }
  }

  public myClass() {
    Package pkg = getClass().getPackage();
    if (pkg == null)
      System.out.println("No Package Found");
    else {
      System.out.println("specs: " + pkg.getSpecificationTitle() + " - " + pkg.getSpecificationVersion());
      System.out.println("imps:  " + pkg.getImplementationTitle() + " - " + pkg.getImplementationVersion());
      System.out.println("name:  " + pkg.getName());
    }
    //other code here excluded from example
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
specs: null - null
imps:  null - null
name:  com.example.package1
```

So what gives?  It looks like the pkg object is being defined correctly, but it doesn't read any of the Specification or Implementation properties.

Comment: I think this question answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/reading-my-own-jars-manifest

Comment: @Clayton, Thanks, but I've already been there and tried that.  I've tried several options there but get no further than what I have here; package name, but only null values for the properties.

Comment: These methods for retrieving properties from a package should work, otherwise what purpose do they serve?   Am I just interpreting too much into their function against the manifest.mf file in the jar?  I feel like I must be missing something simple.  It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally figured it out and thought I'd share incase anyone else was banging their head against the proverbial brick wall as much as I was.  I never could get the methods in the `Package` class to return anything other than `null`. See revised code below for how I managed to pull it off.

```
package com.example.package1;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.jar.*;
import java.net.*;

class myClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    new myClass();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
    System.out.println("Done");
    try{Thread.sleep(40000);}catch(Exception ee){}
    }
  }

public myClass() throws Exception {
  String clz = getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class";
  String pth = getClass().getResource(clz).toString();
  String mnf = pth.substring(0, pth.lastIndexOf("!") + 1) + "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
  String pkg = getClass().getPackage().getName().replaceAll("\\.","/");
  URL url = new URL(mnf);
  Manifest manifest = new Manifest(url.openStream());

  Attributes attr = manifest.getAttributes(pkg);
  String value = attr.getValue("Specification-Title") + " - " + 
  attr.getValue("Implementation-Title") + " " + 
  attr.getValue("Specification-Version") + " build # " + 
  attr.getValue("Implementation-Version");
  System.out.println(value);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
MyPackage - MP v1.1 build # 2015-11-05-C
Done
```

Which is a lot of code to extract four pieces of Metadata.

So if you like a few less lines here's what I used instead:

```
public myClass() throws Exception {
  Attributes attr = new Manifest(new URL(getClass().getResource(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class").toString().substring(0, getClass().getResource(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class").toString().lastIndexOf("!") + 1) + "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF").openStream()).getAttributes(getClass().getPackage().getName().replaceAll("\\.","/"));
  String value = attr.getValue("Specification-Title") + " - " + attr.getValue("Implementation-Title") + " " + attr.getValue("Specification-Version") + " build # " + attr.getValue("Implementation-Version");
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

my approach

```
public class JarInspector {
    
    public static void printInfo(String[] args){
        if(args.length == 1 && "--info".equals(args[0])){
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = JarInspector.class.getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF").openStream();
                Manifest manifest = new Manifest(inputStream);
                Attributes attrs = manifest.getMainAttributes();
                if(attrs == null){
                    throw new RuntimeException("no attributes found");
                }
                Set<Object> keys = attrs.keySet();
                for(Object key:keys){
                    System.out.println(String.format("%s: %s", key,attrs.get(key)));
                }
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            java.lang.System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public class MyMainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //print info jar only if it is called with --info 
         JarInspector.printInfo(args);
    }
}
```

how to use:

```
java -c myapp.jar MyMainApp --info
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a slash to the end of your package paths. I.e. change `com/example/package1` to `com/example/package1/`. Ask for some class within the package `com.example.package1` (we'll call it Foo) and everything should work fine.

```
Package pkg = com.example.package1.class.getPackage();
String specVer = pkg.getSpecificationVersion();
```

The trailing slash seems to matter. E.g. here's the manifest from Apache's `ant.jar`:

```
Name: org/apache/tools/ant/
Extension-name: org.apache.tools.ant
Specification-Title: Apache Ant
Specification-Version: 1.9.6
Specification-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: org.apache.tools.ant
Implementation-Version: 1.9.6
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
```