# Read META-INF/MANIFEST.MF from JAR

Tags: java

This is very odd. I try to read the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF from the application itself:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

But the MANIFEST.MF is another one:

```
jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

This worked in the past, but now it locates it in another JAR! Very, very odd.

**UPDATED**

Tried this as suggested by **haraldK** but the returned enumeration is empty, so nothing is printed:

```
try {
    Enumeration<URL> manifests = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

    while(manifests.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL url = manifests.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Es: > " + url);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the class loader and the order of the JARs on the class path, this is just normal behavior. As there are multiple instances of `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, which one you actually get is dependent on the class loader (that loaded the current class, as returned by `getClass()` in your code).

Instead, you can use `ClassLoader.getResouces(String)`, which will give you an enumeration of all the manifests:

```
Enumeration<URL> manifests = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

From that enumeration, you can look for the right one.

Another option, is using the `Package` class, which will give you easy access to the information from the manifest for your class/package:

```
Package myPackage = getClass().getPackage();
myPackage.getImplementationTitle();
myPackage.getImplementationVersion();
myPackage.getImplementationVendor();
```

Comment: Tried as suggested but the returned enumeration is empty, so nothing is printed :-\

Comment: Try skipping the leading slash (ie. `getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")`). Might have been a copy/paste bug.

Comment: Without the starting slash returns a bunch of URLs, but none of them referring the wanted JAR (some JDK libraries, some Maven dependencies, ...)  :/

Comment: It was something related to IntelliJ because if I execute the application from command line, the resource appears in the right JAR (second entry because the first one is jfxrt.jar from JDK).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GetClass().getResource behaviour depends on implementation of classloader: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html
Maybe your application got additional classloader?

Similar question is here: [Reading my own Jar's Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/reading-my-own-jars-manifest)

Comment: Well, it worked a couple of weeks ago. Maybe the new Java 8 release had some changes related to this behaviour. Thanks!