# Get value from `build.gradle` to code

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

We have a `build.gradle` where the `version` is defined in it. I need to implement a version endpoint ( like `/version`) to get the version of the project. This `version` property in `build.gradle`  has been there for a long time, I can't move it to the `project.properties` file. How can I access this `version`'s values from my Java code?

Comment: Append the value you have in gradle to your properties file before the assemble task or include the version in the manifest file and read it using getResources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways with which you can "plant" information into your code

First you can use the manifest file, and read from it

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      "lib-version": version
  }
}
```

With conjunction to [Reading my own Jar's Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272648/reading-my-own-jars-manifest)

The other option is to add that info the your property files before the jar task

```
task('addVersion') {
    doLast {
       //append the version here, see example
       file("src/main/resources/props.properties").append("version=$version")
    }
}
jar.dependsOn(addVersion)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of our project needs not only the version information but also build time etc. We use a copy task with template substitution.

```
task updateVersions(type: Copy) {
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(file('build.properties')))
    props.put("buildtime", new Date().format("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aa"))
    props.put("version", "${version}")
    from project(':main').file('Version.tmpl')
    into file('src/main/java').path
    expand(props)
    rename('Version.tmpl', 'Version.java')
}
```