# Manage patch info on WAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, manifest, war

What is the best/correct way to manage patches version information on j2ee WAR file

I would like to maintain patch information on a WAR file, so this info could be displayed inside the application once it’s running for maintenance purposes.

was thinking of few possible ways:

1. Using DB table – (I would like to avoid this method)

   - Disadvantages

     - Couple the WAR versions to a DB
     - Additional overhead of database script with the patch.
2. Adding internal XML file to the resources then reading and analyzing/parsing  it

   - Disadvantages

     - Issues accessing the XML (Physical path issues?)
3. Adding the patch info to MANFIEST file

   - Disadvantages

     - Impossible to display it in the app?

I would like to know if there are more ways and what is the best one for such requirement.

Thank you

Comment: Would you like to do it with maven?

Comment: Process to update the version will be done manually. (Exploding the war and updating the files)

Comment: Regarding 1, look into SQLite and embedding the file in the WAR. It's essentially 2, with with something more DB-like. You can avoid path issues by doing [getResourceAsStream()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I would go with the second option. It is convinient to open XML file stored in classes directory.

Comment: Patching a web application is not a great practice as it is rarely repeatable. You're better off building and shipping an entire new WAR file with a new version.

Comment: If you are using tomcat, it has some thing called tags.. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your question, you can store your version in many ways:

### 1.DB table

> ```
> pro : ?
> cons: infra dependant, need to update db, can be desynchronized
> conclusion :please avoid that, it is dependant of your infrastructure.
> ```

### 2. Properties File : BEST OPTION !

> ```
> pro: simple to integrate, ressource is localized by java.util.Properties, implement in 15 min.
> cons: ? 
> conclusion: Simple and easy; the best choice for me. Take a look to the code
> ```

### 3. [Manifest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file)

> ```
> pro: may work
> cons: bad practice to use a defined component for another purpose, bad architecture practice
> conclusion: Avoid this solution, it's a bad architecture practice.
> ```

### WINNER: Properties Code example, test it in less than 15 min.

```
public static Properties loadProperties() {
        String resourceName = "version.properties";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(DBTools.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName));
            logger.trace(String.format("config file %s loadded with success !", resourceName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(String.format("config file %s is not loaded!", resourceName));
        }
        return prop;
    }



  version.properties File 
    APP-VERSION=1.12.4-REV2345-NIGHT
```

in your app when you want to retrieve the app_version, simply do :

```
property.getProperty("APP-VERSION");
```

Comment: User wants changelog, not just the version. And for the version, he can use the MANIFEST file already for this. See my answer

Comment: You're right, we can do it like that. It's only a question of architecture / Design Philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

with the manifest.mf, this file must be regenerated with every build including this entries:

```
Implementation-Title: The value is a string that defines the title of the extension implementation.
Implementation-Version: The value is a string that defines the version of the extension implementation.
Implementation-Vendor: The value is a string that defines the organization that maintains the extension implementation.
Implementation-Vendor-Id: The value is a string id that uniquely defines the organization that maintains the  extension implementation.
Implementation-URL: This attribute defines the URL from which the extension implementation can be downloaded from.
Specification-Title: The value is a string that defines the title of the extension specification.
Specification-Version: The value is a string that defines the version of the extension specification.
Specification-Vendor: The value is a string that defines the organization that maintains the extension specification.
```

here is the discution about how to read it from a servlet [How to read MANIFEST.MF inside WAR application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239368/how-to-read-manifest-mf-inside-war-application)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use MANIFEST for this. Create your own changelog file format, bundle it inside your WAR file in a location known by your application, and create a feature in your application to display this. MANIFEST was not designed for storing changelogs and on the long term will only bring you problems if you go this way. I suggest you add a property that tells you where the changelog of that version is located. For example:

```
--- MANIFEST ----
Application-Version: 1.2.5
My-App-Changelog: /WEB-INF/changelogs/version-1.2.5.xml
-----------------
```

Depending on the application server or web container you are using, you may be able to create an extension or another app= that introspect all deployed WARs and displays this information. You will be required to use vendor-specific APIs.

Everytime you release a new version, that archive will contain the version number and changelogs of all versions, which is good for quick tracking of changes.