# java: Get manifest file of my war from a webservice request

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm working on a webapp which have webservices.

I'm to get build version, specification title etc which are then in the manifest file to respond to the resful service

For a web request I can do below. How can I access the manifest resource from a webservice request

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")`

Answer (score 2):

By reading the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html), it looks like that the package information only exists in the JAR file. which was generated by 
`jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt yourPackage/*.class`

and the Manifest.txt would be:

> Name: java/util/
> Specification-Title: Java Utility Classes
> Specification-Version: 1.2
> Specification-Vendor: Example Tech, Inc.
> Implementation-Title: java.util
> Implementation-Version: build57
> Implementation-Vendor: Example Tech, Inc.

Comment: ok. that makes sense. my app is a war file but still has the mf file with required details. any ideas on how i read that

Comment: @Sudhik Maybe you want this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239368/how-to-read-manifest-mf-inside-war-application

Comment: Thanks I got it to work for web requests. How about webservice requests

Comment: For those one uses Spring, I found useful this solution in webservices where don't have ServletContext: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25700939/2186777