# Load Maven POM version number into Java Project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want to add a version numbering to my Java application (in this case a Vaadin Portlet) which features the Version number in the help view.

The thing is that that version number is the one defined in the my Maven's POM file (for example 1.1.5-SNAPSHOT) and that is the one we are going to change (at release for example).

Any idea on how to get it out of the POM and into (for example, a String) in Java? (If this is at all possible)

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a **filtered** properties file containing the line

```
version=${project.version}
```

and load this properties file from the classpath in your Java program.

Comment: Who sets properties file and can I get the value of a project.version from a Java method without using a properties file etc. Can you check my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760638/how-to-get-maven-project-version-from-java-class-as-like-at-pom

Answer (score 4):

There are many solutions to this problem

- Have [maven write the version number in MANIFEST.MF](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) during packaging phase
- Create a filtered properties file, like JB mentionned
- Have one Java class rewritten with that property

But I would defintely prefer the first, as accessing MANIFEST.MF is quite easy in Java

Comment: How would one access the information in the manifest in a Java application?

Comment: @Deejay let me stackoverflow it for you : http://stackoverflow.com/q/615493/15619

Answer (score 2):

The version in the POM is available as a property "project.version". Expressed as ${project.version}

So you should be able to use it with filtering resources:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

The nicest approach would probably be to filter (and replace) a properties file or a deployment descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could read the maven pom.properties from classpath. The pom.properties are located at:
META-INF/maven/groupid/artifactId/pom.properties

Comment: This would cause a dependency on the Maven build. I'd rather use the MANIFEST.MF file which contains the same information defined a standard manner.