# Reading Manifest File Inside of Jar with Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, ant, jar, manifest.mf

I think I'm making a simple mistake, but perhaps you guys can help me out. I have a Jetty webserver. I have deployed a servlet under:

```
{Jetty-Folder}/webapps/BotServlet/WEB-INF
                                 --------/lib/Server_BotServlet.jar
                                 --------/web.xml
```

So the servlet inside of Server_BotServlet starts up appropriate and I can access it through the appropriate url. My problem is now the manifest file inside of Server_BotServlet.jar.

```
Server_BotServlet.jar
----> /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

The Manifest file is added using an ANT script in eclipse and forms:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Built-Date: 2014-04-01 18:53:54
Built-Version: 2014-04-01 18:53:54
```

**Problem: I am unable to read the manifest file using the following code in the webserver:**

```
    InputStream inputStream = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
    if(inputStream == null) {System.out.println("Input stream is null1");}
    try {
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest(inputStream);
        Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
        versionString = attributes.getValue("Built-Version");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        versionString = "N/A";
    }
```

What happens is the `InputStream` always ends up equaling `null`. In another case, I had it print out `getServletContext().getContextPath` and it shows me `"/BotServlet/"` as it should. Correct me if I am wrong, but when a jar is loaded at runtime, it gets "run" from the contextpath? Or am I going about deploying these jar's incorrectly as the getResourceAsStream() does not seem to see the jar file appropriately.

I am using the method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615493/how-do-i-read-the-manifest-file-for-a-webapp-running-in-apache-tomcat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Servlet context is `/BotServlet/` not into the `/BotServlet/WEB-INF/lib/Server_BotServlet.jar` file. You could put a file you want to read in `/WEB-INF/lib/myfile.txt` and access that - or you could open the jar (`/BotServlet/WEB-INF/lib/Server_BotServlet.jar`) and read your MANIFEST. Really it depends on what your ultimate objectives are.