# Why am I getting the wrong MANIFEST?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to access the MANIFEST.MF file in my  java application.

I'm doing the following

```
   //prints /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    System.out.println( "We are looking at "+this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                        .getResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));` 
//Im looking to print  /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/MyProject/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF


//prints-/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/lib/
System.out.println("The base path is"+this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                        .getResource("."));
```

Here's the directory structure

```
MyProject
-src/main/java/my/packages/MyClass.java
-target
   -MyProject.war
```

Any thoughts on how I can correct my code would be great.

Directory structure of my war

```
Myproject
META-INF            apidocs             other folders
WEB-INF
```

Comment: what is the dir structure of your MyProject.war ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: added directory structure

Comment: @Kroyo. Im doing exactly the same as the answer and facing this problem.

Comment: when you launch the app, how does your classpath look like /

Comment: @JigarJoshi.: I don't quite get you. Isn't your question answered in the base path I am printing out? OR are you looking for something different?

Comment: @Kroyo I'm following the other answer and I get a different MANIFEST. Presumably of another jar(application1.1.jar!) being referenced by my application. Hope that clears it.

Comment: This question is pointing to the wrong duplicate. It should be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615493/how-do-i-read-the-manifest-file-for-a-webapp-running-in-apache-tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the ServletContext.getResourceAsStream

I have found the classloader method not as reliable for MANIFEST files on web apps.

Also it's not going to reliably work well if your running your app from maven or eclipse wtp if your manifest is generated by your build process.

The real duplicate of the question: [How do I read the manifest file for a webapp running in apache tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615493/how-do-i-read-the-manifest-file-for-a-webapp-running-in-apache-tomcat)

Comment: Do you have a code snippet to back this up? I'm not using a web app. Would I have access to the ServletContext?

Comment: Why do you have tomcat paths in your examples? I'll post code later (on phone currently).

Comment: thats the result of `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` which *should* return the absolute path to the current class

Comment: My manifest is auto generated by maven. So what options do I have?

Comment: How are you executing the project? It still looks like tomcat is running your code. Btw when I mean webapp I mean your code is running in a servlet container like tomcat even if it does no webapp like behavior.

Comment: :Actually this **seems** to be working atm. Is it production worthy?

**EDIT** In response to your comment. Yes, I was able to gain access to servletcontext from a web service layer.

Comment: I'm testing/executing this piece of code using POSTMAN.